# The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nest

I Use ElasticSearch 8.1.2
and Nest 17.7.1

```cs
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"))
            .CertificateFingerprint("A5:8B:07:2D:A9:E8:53:CE:GB:C0:15:CE:6E:DF:9C:65:89:A3:AC:D2:94:2C:46:BD:85:23:20:6B:F2:69:B3:88")
            .BasicAuthentication("elastic", "-L-uXRg5=iOXGFgebP68")                  
            .DeadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300))
            .DefaultIndex("people");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var person = new Person
{
    Id = 1,
    FirstName = "Martijn",
    LastName = "Laarman"
};
var asyncIndexResponse = await client.IndexDocumentAsync(person);
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

But I have Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUXGO.png)

error message:
Message = "The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. Call: Status code unknown from: GET /"

Comment: Have you looked at this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/6148 ? Shouldn't you should be using `https`

Comment: @Paulo : I wants to use http  but http not works for me

Comment: i get This page isn’t working in http://localhost:9200

Comment: On the lastest version, security is enable by default. So is you did not disable it. Elasticsearch is going to use `HTTPS`.

Comment: @Paulo  i set user and password and CA but connot connect to elastic and i have error

Comment: Not the case here, but I have had this error a few times, where I accidentally was trying to connect client to the kibana url instead of the elastic endpoint...

Answer (score 5):

Enable the compatibility header in the connection settings:

```
settings.EnableApiVersioningHeader(); // enable ES 7.x compatibility on ES 8.x servers
```

[Docu here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/connecting-to-elasticsearch-v8.html#enabling-compatibility-mode) under *Enabling Compatibility Mode*

Comment: thanks
im remove the elasticseatch 8.0.2 and install 7X version and work fine

Comment: Can this work if ES client is 7.x and server is also 7.x? Or is it only good for 8.x server?

Comment: @Tinmar When you read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rest-api-compatibility.html#_rest_api_compatibility_workflow) it says that you should first activate compatibility then updating ES server from 7.x to 8.x. From this workflow you can conclude that the compatibility mode also works with 7.x servers.

Comment: Thanks! But it won't work for me, I am getting similar error as an OP... One more question: Is CertificateFingerprint() method setting always needed, or only for local development as it says [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.17/connecting-to-elasticsearch-v8.html)? I need to migrate this project to support new elasticsearch server and it doesn't have that set.

Comment: @Tinmar This depends on your config. For dev you could also accept any certificates by this: `settings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback((o, cert, chain, errors) => true)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want use http instead https and ElasticSearch by default use SSL/TLS, you can try to disable it by .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  version: 7.6.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 1
    config:
      node.master: true
      node.data: true
      node.ingest: true
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
      xpack.security.authc:
          anonymous:
            username: anonymous
            roles: superuser
            authz_exception: false
  http:
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true
```

This is an example file, but consider the "http" part: this allow you to disable https and expose your elasticSearch in http.