# Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on POST: when trying to run a console app in C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to elastic search. I am trying to use the code to search text. getting the Error "{Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on POST: /foo/_doc}" when trying to run the code. I think I am missing something how to use Nest nuGet any help is welcome

```
   using IdentityServer4.Models;
   using Nest;
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9200"))
            .DefaultIndex("foo");
         var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var indexName = "indexName";
        if (client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
        {
            client.DeleteIndex(indexName);
        }
        var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(an => an
                        .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                            .Tokenizer("standard")
                            .CharFilters("html_strip")
                            .Filters("lowercase")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .Mappings(m => m
                .Map<Document>(mp => mp
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Title)
                            .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                        )
                        .Text(t => t
                            .Name(n => n.Content)
                            .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        var doc = new Document
        {
            Title = "Friends are friendlier friendlies that are friendly and classify the friendly classification class.",
            // Remove stop word like are, and, that,the
            Content = "Flowery flowers flow through following the flower flows."
        };
        var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(doc);
        // Error occurred here 
         Console.WriteLine(indexResponse.Result);
         Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
```

Document class

```
class Document
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Debugging Information

"Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful () low level call on PUT: /indexName\r\n# Audit trail of this API call:\r\n - [1] ProductCheckOnStartup: Took: 00:00:02.0264861\r\n - [2] ProductCheckFailure: Node: http://127.0.0.1:9200/ Took: 00:00:02.0261849\r\n# OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. Call: Status code unknown from: GET /\r\n ---> Elasticsearch.Net.PipelineException: The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product.\r\n ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.ThrowIfTransientProductCheckFailure()\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.RequestPipeline.Ping(Node node)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Ping(IRequestPipeline pipeline, Node node)\r\n   at Elasticsearch.Net.Transport`1.Request[TResponse](HttpMethod method, String path, PostData data, IRequestParameters requestParameters)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n# Request:\r\n<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n# Response:\r\n<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>\r\n"

Comment: If you could enable [debug mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-mode.html) and update question with debug information that would help.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for your reply Debugging information added

Comment: Seems like this is the issue `The client is unable to verify that the server is Elasticsearch due to an unsuccessful product check call. Some functionality may not be compatible if the server is running an unsupported product. `. What NEST version do you use and what Elasticsearch version are you using? May be related [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058718/the-client-is-unable-to-verify-that-the-server-is-elasticsearch-due-to-an-unsucc).

Comment: @Rob NEST version 7.17.5 its the latest version